# Compare only Date in nHibernate Linq on a DateTime value

Tags: linq, nhibernate, datetime, date, compare

I trying to compare two dates (DateTime) in nHibernate linq:

```
query = query.Where(l => (l.datCriacao.Date == dtLote.Date)
```

but I am getting the error:

```
NHibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property: datCriacao.Date of: SAGP.Entities.Lote
```

Anyone knows how I can solve this? Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I solved the problem doing a between with the dates:

```
DateTime initialDate, finalDate;
initialDate= DateEntity.Date;
finalDate= new DateTime(DateEntity.Year, DateEntity.Month, DateEntity.Day, 23, 59, 59);
query = query.Where(l => (((l.dateEntity>= initialDate) && (l.dateEntity<= finalDate))
```

Comment: I know it's old but this is bad example because dateEntity can be 23:59:59.200 and will be out off any range. Chris M gave better answer.

Answer (score 5):

This is super old, but I'd add to jaspion's example as:

```
query = query.Where(l => (l.datCriacao >= dtLote.Date && l.datCriacao < dtLote.Date.AddDays(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the condition like this

var nextDay = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);

query = query.Where(l => (l.datCriacao >= dtLote && l.datCriacao < nextDay);

here you'll get the records on dtLote date as we checking between dtLote and dtLote+1 day (00:00:00) we'll get today's date record only what ever may be the time...